# Prevent a file & directory from direct access but allowing it from your main domain only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I have 3 domains(frontend,backend,assets) hosted on single server with all my assets files on particular directory `/assets/` pointing to `http://assets.mydomain.com/`

I want to prevent direct access to my files and directory from users and allow my all other domains to have access to the files. I googled it alot found some solutions using `.htaccess` and set `deny all`  but that's not working in my case coz of different domains I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples about this at [`Order`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order)

> In the following example, all hosts in the example.org domain are allowed access; all other hosts are denied access.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from example.com
```

This excludes all hosts, except your own domain (example.com).

When you have access to the main configuration, you can also restrict this to a particular directory with [`Directory`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)

```
 <Directory /path/to/assets>
...
</Directory>
```

If not, put the `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` directives in an .htaccess file in the assets directory.

Comment: In `/assets/` directory which is root of `htttp://assets.mydomain.com/` I put a .htaccess file with
`Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from mydomain.com`
but I am getting 403 forbidden for all my files in it

Comment: `deny allow` is working but `allow from` is not working

Comment: Have you tried getting the file from the specified domain? In my test environment, I tried `curl --interface frontend.example.com assets.example.com`, which gives me the requested `index.html`. While with `curl --interface www.test.com assets.example.com`, I get a 403.

Comment: yeah I did try but coz of some odd reasons `allow from` is not working, in all cases I am getting 403

Comment: I found the problem , `Allow from` only works when I enter user ip in it ,

Comment: Ok, maybe there's some problem with DNS? I tested with all the host names in /etc/hosts.

Comment: what I want is `assets.mydomain.com` only allow when http reffer is `mydomain.com`

Comment: Hey @Olaf thanks for showing me the directions, I found the solution :) thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

**This worked for me**

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://yourdomain.com/" letitpass
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=letitpass
```

I put this code in `.htaccess` in root directory i.e `/assets/` of `http"//assets.yourdomain.com`

Comment: `Referer` is not safe for authentication or access control. A client might fake a Referer header and gain access to your content. If this should protect sensitive data then use another technique.

Comment: Since your question is tagged [hotlinking], it might be sufficient. See also https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html

Comment: @Olaf can you suggest me something which is more secure, I am kinda noob in these things

Comment: I think to prevent hotlinking, your solution is good enough. Only when you try to protect important data, you should use a more secure method. For example, since all domains are on the same server, you might move assets away from document root and access it directly instead of via HTTP. This way you won't need any access control at all. But this also depends on your infrastructure and your web application.